# NoSuchMethodError: de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.StanfordSegmenter.isWriteToken()Z

Tags: uima, ruta, dkpro-core

**Script**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//      DKPRO - Imports
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos FROM  GeneratedDKProCoreTypes AS pos;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Lemma FROM GeneratedDKProCoreTypes;

UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.StanfordSegmenter;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger.TreeTaggerPosLemmaTT4J;//TreeTaggerPosTagger
//------------------------------------------------------------------------


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//      DKPRO - Execution
//-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------

Document{-CONTAINS(pos.POS)} -> {
Document{-> SETFEATURE("language", "en")}; //"de"
Document{-> EXEC(StanfordSegmenter)};
Document{-> EXEC(TreeTaggerPosLemmaTT4J, {pos.POS})};//(TreeTaggerPosTagger, {pos.POS})};
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//      DKPRO - Test
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE DZC_DkProTest;
pos.NP{-> MARK(DZC_DkProTest)};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Error in short**

```
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.StanfordSegmenter.isWriteToken()Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method isWriteToken() that's part of StanfordSegmenter is not found, which causes the error. Either it doesn't exist or you misspelled it.

Don't really know what else to tell you without more info.

Comment: Ya I already searched for the method but couldn't find.. That's why I posted the question. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

I changed the DKPro Core version in Maven from 1.5.0 to 1.7.0 and then the issue got resolved. I could locate the isWriteToken() method in de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.SegmenterBase class.